# What is the meaning of this symbol that looks like an inverted uppercase A?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, notation

I found this symbol in a book I'm reading. Does anyone know what this symbol means? Does it mean for all js?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's universal quantifier that interpreted as "given any" or "for all". you can check [definition of quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)).

Comment: Correct, but I'll add that the phrase is $\forall{j{\neq}i}$, not just $\forall{j}$

Comment: @ZacharyVance Actually $\forall j\neq i$ is an abbreviation, which is not fully formalized, but usually does not raise interpretation issues. The proper form is 
$\forall j \in S : P(j)$ where $S$ is the set of all values that can be taken by the quantified variable $j$, and the predicate $P$ must be verified for each value.

Comment: I'm commenting on the highlighted phrase, not your answer. Think like a beginner. The highlighted phrase is not quite how you should read it: In english, "For all j, not equal to i P(x)" doesn't read correctly. Instead, highlight the phrase I list: in english "For all j not equal to i, P(x)" makes sense.